# In Excel how do I extract the address referenced in another cell's equation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I have a grid of stock data, where the rows are call prices and the columns are put prices. For each cell in the grid I can generate a graph of results for that particular call/put combination. I want to use the spreadsheet interactively by clicking on a grid cell and seeing the graph corresponding to that particular cell. I want to do this without any VB and without any add-ons. I'm very close and am just missing one function.

I want to be able to click on a cell by my graph, type "=", and then click on the grid cell for which I want the graph, so I get a result like "=R12". I want it to derive that I'm interested in a graph related to cell R12.

What I can do now is have two cells containing the row and column numbers of interest. I can then use =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Z20,1)) and  =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,Z21)) to get row and column header values of the cell referenced by Z20,Z21. I can also use the =ROW() and =COLUMN() equations in cells Z20 and Z21, but not conveniently. To choose a different cell to see the graph of, I would have to type "=ROW(", then click on the cell I want, then type ")", and same for column.

I could also type "=", then click on R12, then delete the "=" so the cell contains "R12" but that's kind of clunky, too.

Comment: Assuming the cell you click on is `A1`, something like: `=RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(A1), LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

If your cell you enter "=" and click another cell is D6 then your other formulas can extract the cell you click on with this:

```
=RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(D6),LEN(FORMULATEXT(D6))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row and column like so:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(E18),"=","")))

=COLUMN(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(E18),"=","")))
```

where E18 is the cell you type "=" in and then click a cell (and press Enter).

Those values can be used to collect all of a row or column's entries. (It's not quite clear to me precisely how you intend to use the values, just that you want the row and column that intersect on the clicked cell so it's difficult to address anything past that.)

You could even use the information found to read `Data Types` in the source range you click in. The following gets a cell address that is "live" as in can be used in a Data Type extraction formula:

```
=OFFSET(A1,ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(E18),"=","")))-1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(E18),"=","")))-1)
```

(A1 is cell "1,1" so you have to subtract 1 from each of the row and column values.)

Many times one cannot extract Data Type from a cell that is filled by a formula, but this is a live address and so it is what Excel sees, not the formula under it. So, say you do the "=, click a cell, press Enter" thing in E18 and have the above formula in E19, then you could have a formula like:

```
=E19.price
```

to get the stock's price (for whatever cell in the range you clicked).

I mention that just as a side note, and because of how you phrase things. It half feels like you have Data Type results in your source, and half feels like you are making a graph on either the column or row data even though you make it sound like the graph would include (somehow making sense!) both series of data.